# Element requiring 2 clicks until it shows

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a quote form appear on click, the element is first prepended it then needs to run through ajax to get the content for the element

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="used_result_icon used_result_nav_enquire" car="'.$full_listing_name.'" />
```

CSS

```
#used_car_quote {background:#fff; border:2px solid #bebebe; border-radius:5px; display:none; font-size:20px; left:500px; min-height:350px; position:fixed; width:640px; z-index:100;}
```

AJAX

```
$(document).on("click", ".used_result_nav_enquire", function() {
car = $(this).attr('car');
$('#used_car_quote').show();
$('#used_results_sort').prepend('<div id="used_car_quote"></div>');
$.ajax({  
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'http://localhost/carprice/ajax/used-quote-results.php',
    data : 'car='+car,
    success : function(data) {
        $("#used_car_quote").html(data);
    }
}); 
});
```

Its very strange, I click on the button once, and nothing happens, then I click again, and the form appears.

Comment: this `$('#used_car_quote').show();` should be placed after the `$('#used_results_sort').prepend(...`

Comment: did not understand the logic, first your are making 'used_car_quote' visible then prepending it to 'used_results_sort'. Here you are creating new div with same id = 'used_car_quote' and multiple element with same id will not work.

Comment: King King - already tried that, it didn't work at all, this way worked after two clicks.

Comment: Bhushan Kawadkar - the logic is that it is actually used on a different page, and I wanted to keep the same styling. The ajax then calls the same method used on that different page, so it is all kept consistent. The element starts by being hidden though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in AJAX Success    `$('#used_car_quote').show();`

```
$(document).unbind("click").bind('click', ".used_result_nav_enquire", function() {
car = $(this).attr('car');

$('#used_results_sort').prepend('<div id="used_car_quote"></div>');
$.ajax({  
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'http://localhost/carprice/ajax/used-quote-results.php',
    data : 'car='+car,
    success : function(data) {
        $("#used_car_quote").html(data);
        $("#used_car_quote").show();
    }
}); 
});
```

Comment: That seems to work, can you explain whats happening, I am not that familiar with bind().

Comment: Actually its a good habit to use UNBIND and BIND, if your code is executing for two times then JQuery will bind click event two times, with using unbind and bind this will not happen

Comment: `bind` and `unbind` do nothing here. Also they are deprecated. If the OP can be sure about when he registers the click event handlers, it's not necessary to unbind the handlers. At least it works because of this `$("#used_car_quote").show();` which is placed inside the `success` callback. However it's strange that my suggestion does not work.

Comment: @KingKing Yes you are right, so that I mention in my answer that Use this code in AJAX Success  $('#used_car_quote').show(), but as OP wants to know about UNBIND and BIND these why i given explanation.

Comment: Oh King King you are right, when I place show() in success it works, and removing the bind made no difference. I am not sure why yours did not work.

Comment: @user2909486 If its works for you then please mark it as answer so that it will help other too.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to style it as well, but this is very strange, if I click on it once, then it is not positioned right, close it then click again, and it is

```
$(document).on("click", ".used_result_nav_enquire", function() {
win_width = $(window).width();
form_width = $('#used_car_quote').width();
left = (win_width-form_width)/2;
win_height = $(window).height();
form_height = $('#used_car_quote').height();
top = (win_height-form_height)/2;
car = $(this).attr('car');
$('#used_results_sort').prepend('<div id="used_car_quote">test</div>');
$('#used_car_quote').css({'left':left,'top':top});
$.ajax({  
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'http://localhost/carprice/ajax/used-quote-results.php',
    data : 'car='+car,
    success : function(data) {
        $("#used_car_quote").html(data);
        $('#used_car_quote').show();
    }
}); 
});
```

Comment: why are u pasting the same answer which is accepted below

Comment: this new problem is in fact not new, it's strange like as the problem you asked in the question. So just place `$('#used_car_quote').css({'left':left,'top':top});` inside the success callback, however note about the context here (I mean about accessing the `left` and `top` variables inside the success callback).

Comment: Sure, I thought of that as well, and tried it, putting it before and after the show(), but still the same result. Hence it being a new problem.

Comment: @user2909486 it maybe because of the access to `left` and `top` inside  the success callback, I'm not sure if using it directly like that is OK. You can try such as alerting the values or using `console.log` to print them (inside the success callback) to see if you can access the `left` and `top` variables.